# Creating a custom input method

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, input-languages

Is there any standard way of creating a custum input method for X11/linux in general?

I've poked around scim and iBus but I can't seem to find any example of it having been done before.

In reality I need to create a custom keyboard layout with much more Mod keys than presently exist in solutions like xkbmap.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an input method for X11 is really a software development task rather than a user task. Thus this question might be more appropriate on the site **[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)**. The following questions might be helpful:

- *[Use xkbdmap to map rwin to altgr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799071/use-xkbdmap-to-map-rwin-to-altgr)*
- *[How do I map an X11 keysym to a Unicode character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268600/how-do-i-map-an-x11-keysym-to-a-unicode-character)*, which points to Markus Kuhn's *[keysym2ucs.c code](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/keysym2ucs.c)*.

The [X.org documentation](http://www.x.org/wiki/Documentation) points out that Xlib is a widely used API for the X11, but that for new development, a toolkit such as [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php) or [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/) is preferred.

Xlib has a documented way of *[Manipulating the Keyboard Encoding](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/libX11/libX11.html#Manipulating_the_Keyboard_Encoding)*. If that isn't enough control, it also has a documented *[Input Methods interface](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/libX11/libX11.html#Input_Methods)*.

The GTK API offers [*Key Values*, "Functions for manipulating keyboard codes"](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Keyboard-Handling.html).